# How can I adjust the x-axis of a matplotlib.pyplot histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib

total noob here.  I need to create a histogram, and it is coming out terribly.

[image: terrible histogram]

As you can see it generates one large bar for all 150,000 data points.  The range is a percent, so almost all of the values should between 0 and 1.  I want to see what is happening between 0 and 1, not that most all of the values are between 0 and 1.

Here is the code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/data.csv')

df['DebtRatio'].hist();
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 2, 0.1))
```

How can I get this histogram to actually be a histogram and show me the distribution across the lowest and most prominent end of the range?

Thanks

Comment: That's not quite right. The largest value in the `' DebtRatio'` column is `329664.0`, therefore the histogram extends up to this point. Best step back a bit and analyze what data you have and become clear about their meaning.

Comment: Thank you.  I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest your actual values range from 0 to 329664, which explain why your histogram looks like that.

If you're sure that it must be a ratio (between 0 and 1), then you can filter your rows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/data.csv')

    print(df['DebtRatio'].describe())  # Look a the max value
    df['DebtRatio'].loc[df['DebtRatio'] <= 1].hist()  # Plot an histogram of filtered values
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I needed.